# Permanent links format in wordpress: How to Choose?

Tags: seo, wordpress

In WordPress, I have the option to choose how the permanent URL looks like.

The common format is Year/Month/Day or Year/Month for blogs. However, I’ve occasionally seen some successful blogs take the date out, such as: http://mixergy.com/dane-maxwell-zannee-interview/

What’s the impact of the above format on SEO?

Obviously, it’s more pleasant on the eye but does it negatively impact search ranking?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no REAL SEO value/impact with regards to this - there are many equally successful sites with both variations. If your blog becomes important enough, then it's worth having the date included (or a unique numeric number to abide by [Google News guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68323)) but other than that it's purely a personal preference.

It's worth pointing out that there are scalability issues around using %category% or %postname% only in the permalink structure, see http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/ for more information

Answer (score 1):

oh its way better to have your URL as the post title

simply edit the permalinks under the general settings

choose custom structure

then insert this string

/%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer just a unique number and the slug. The software then uses only the unique number to determine what content to show, and still works if the slug gets corrupted or changes. Just like SO does.